# AWS security group change

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-route53, security-groups

I modified the security group for two VMs on AWS (from one security group to another - not just editing the security rules of an existing group).  The VM's are behind Amazon ELB (and using Route 53).  After the security group change (and without rebooting the VM's), I can access the service on the two VM's using the IP address but I cannot access the service via the URL.  Any idea on whether I need to configure anything on Route 53 to activate this security group change correctly?

One more thing:
the traceroute is ending at an IP address owned by Amazon.

**Update:**

I have all ports open on the inbound and outbound (numbers changed) 100, 101 and 102 for the ELB security group and for the security group being used by the internal VM is configured for port 100, 101 and 102 (for inbound) and all open for outbound.

After this change, I can see that the traceroute is ending at an Amazon instance (but not the internal instance I am running).

Comment: Do you also need to adjust the security group(s) for your ELB?

Comment: thanks @Castaglia I modifed that as well but the URL access is not working (direct ip is working)

Comment: modifying security group for ELB to allow all traffic on incoming and specific ports for outbound (just for ELB)

Comment: What about network ACLs?